# push $_ output into array

Tags: arrays, perl

I am using `$_\n` to have line break for out output. How to push below `"$_\n" for @new` output into array?

```
foreach $fruit_list (@fruit_list){
        @fruitcheck = qx(grep -oP "fruit\\s+$fruit_list\\K\\s+\\S+\\s+[1-9]" $file);
        chomp @fruitcheck;
        @new = grep(/\S+\s+[1-9]/gm, @fruitcheck); 
        chomp @new;
        @new = map {join(' ', split(' '))} @fruitcheck;
        print "$fruit_list: $_\n" for @new;
}
```

File content:

```
fruit     apple     3
fruit     apple     5
fruit     graapes   7
fruit     grapes    0
fruit     mango     9
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want -- to add `"$fruit_list: $_\n"` to an array, for each iteration in the loop?  You don't mean just `push @ary, "$fruit_list: $_\n";` ...?

Comment: Btw, I wouldn't add a newline to each element of an array -- you can always add it when printing (like `say for @ary;`).  Better keep only the actual data in the array.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is this:

```perl
my @array;
while ( <> ) {
   chomp;
   my ( $type, $item, $count ) = split ' ';
   next if $type ne "fruit";  # Needed? Wanted?

   push @array, "$item: $count\n";
}
```

That said, it's more customary to store data in a usable format, and only convert it to a printable format when needed. Following that ideal, one would use the following instead:

```perl
push @array, [ $item, $count ];
```

Or maybe a hash would make more sense.

```perl
$hash{ $item } += $count;
```

---

Tip: Make sure to ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;` (or equivalent). I left it out above as is customary, because it's understood that it's always used.